Accessing folder through os.scandir() after changes made to folder
I am trying to iterate through a folder with html files to filter them according to whether they contain a keyword or not in their string form. I download them to a folder through wget and BeautifulSoup and iterate through it after downloading with os.scandir() and copy the passing files to a different folder. However, first time I run the script, I can only download them, and no file will be copied to the destination directory. When I run it a second time, it does filter properly.
I am guessing that when I first run the script, os.scandir() automatically copies the initial state of the first folder(which is empty). But I couldn't make it so that os.scandir() assumes the final state of the folder with HTML data.How can I make it so that I can iterate through the data after downloading? Here is the snippet:
#pull HTML data from links with wget
subprocess.Popen(bash_commandList,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

job_as_string = ""

#search for keyword in html as string to detect if the jobstelle has something I can do
with os.scandir('/Users/user/wgetLinks') as parent:
    for job_stelle in parent:
        with open(job_stelle, 'r') as f:
            if job_stelle.name.endswith(".html") and job_stelle.is_file():
                print(job_stelle.name)
                job_as_string = f.read()
        f.close()
        for keyword in keywords:
            if(keyword in job_as_string):
                popen_Command = '/Users/user/wgetLinks/' + job_stelle.name
                shutil.copy(popen_Command, '/Users/user/wgetInformatics')
                continue```


Nit pick: you have open(job_stelle, 'r') in a with block, so the f.close() afterwards is unnecessary because the with block handles it for you

Yeah, I was a bit desperate at debugging it so it just stayed like that while I was trying new stuff ':D
